# Setup SFTP in Ubuntu AMI

Tags: linux, sftp, amazon-ec2

I want to setup SFTP on Amazon Ubuntu AMI. I can connect to the instance with PuTTY and access my project file through normal FTP (using Filezilla). For FTP access `proftp` is installed in Webmin.

Can someone please explain how to setup SFTP to make my connections to my instance more secure?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP or http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_setup_an_sftp-server.

Answer (score 0):

[sftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) is an extension of the SSH protocol.  An SFTP server is built into `openssh-server`.  So if you can connect to your instance with PuTTY, then use the same connection details (hostname, port, username, password/key) to create an `sftp` connection with your ftp client.

Comment: how to connect it throurgh filzilla. I have both .pem and .ppk key . please tell where to add key file in filezilla

Comment: It's a bit convoluted, https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto I personally prefer [WinSCP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/)

Comment: Now connection is establish but some of my folder is not accessible. it shows Error: Directory /home/template: permission denied
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: You'll have to give yourself permissions to the directories through a Putty session